# Retract flags from the "Flagged Posts for [User]" page

Tags: script, flags

### Description

In response to a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) on Meta Stack Overflow: [Allow retracting flags on deleted posts even if you can't view deleted posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333954/3853934), I created a userscript which allows you to retract flags directly from the "Flagged Posts for [User]" page in the user profile.

[image]

### Instalation

Click the following link: <kbd>[Install](https://github.com/Gothdo/UserScripts/raw/master/so-retract-flags.user.js)</kbd>

### Knows issues

#### Comment flags

As far as I know, there's no way to determine whether a flag is a post flag or a comment flag, so the script displays a "retract" button next to both types of flag; but as comment flags cannot be retracted, you get an error when trying to retract a comment flag.

### Bugs

Please report any bugs on [the Issues page on the GitHub repository](https://github.com/Gothdo/UserScripts/issues).

Comment: The only way I found to make the distinction (apart from parsing the text as obsolete / too chatty / ... which won't work for custom flags), is to make the userscript work only when `group` is a URL parameter with a value different than 4 (meaning, you're not filtering by comment flags).

Comment: I was just about to recommend this userscript to a user in chat, as I've previously done. Unfortunately, the GitHub repository links are 404. Hopefully, that's just an oversight. If so, it would be helpful if you could update this question with the new location for the script, that would be helpful. Alternately, or in addition, if you'd be willing to release the script under an open source license, that could also work. Thanks for making the script. I've found it quite useful over the years I've used it.

Comment: If the issue is that you've lost access to this userscript's code, I can provide you with a copy. Obviously, because of copyright issues, I'm not permitted to give it to other people (i.e. I'm not permitted to distribute it).

Comment: @Makyen I created something similar: [FlagRetractor](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/FlagRetractor.user.js)

Comment: Please give us more information about the current status. The links is dead and no reaction from you in a long time. If you don't want to continue the distribution of the script, I think it would be appropriate to delete your posts about recommending and promoting it as well to not confuse anyone. Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the links to the source and install website went dead. I'm keeping this for reference in case someone else gets inspired by this and creates a new, fresh script or app.